# How to Reduce Unused JavaScript in a Next.js Project Deployed on Vercel

Tags: performance, next.js, vercel, pagespeed

I need help with reducing unused JavaScript in a Next.js project that's been deployed on Vercel. PageSpeed points out the file /_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-cc48c28d170fddc2.js as an issue. I've tried reviewing the code, but the problem still exists. Does anyone have suggestions for tackling this in Next.js?

[DIAGNOSTICS PageSpeed Insights Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEWut.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this in Next.js on Vercel?

Comment: Are you using any linting tool such ESLint? if so, were you able to build the project locally? If that is not the case for you, try to use ESlLint, it will show you how to better optimize the code. When you resolve all linting errors/warnings try to build it locally. if that works then push your changes to vercel so it can re-build and deploy your app.